# Unable to deploy war file in to citrus embedded jetty server

Tags: citrus-framework

As per reference in the citrus documentation I am trying to deploy a war file in to citrus embedded jetty server but the server is not deploying the war file. Here is the part of configuration file for jetty server actions

```
<citrus-http:server id="helloHttpServer"
                    port="8080"
                    auto-start="true"
                    resource-base="src/test/resources"/>
```

under the resource-base I had placed a .war file which is working fine while executing in external jetty server but citrus was not deploying in its embedded server.

Comment: I do not see any hint in the documentation that describes how to deploy a war file in the citrus-http:server. Can you please point me to the specific part in the documentation? If there is such a hint it is wrong as you are not able to deploy war files in that server component by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able and you are not supposed to deploy any war files to the citrus-http:server component. The server accepts all incoming requests and forwards those to the running test case. In case you want to deploy some system under test WAR please use another web application server in a separate JVM.